# Enable CORS not working globally

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, cors

In my `Web API` project I have enabled CORS globally by adding following line in `WebApiConfig`

```
config.EnableCors();
```

but it still give me error while I request service from other App Domain.

However it works fine if I apply `[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]` on controller level.

Why it doesn't work for application level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define a global rule, you can pass that into `EnableCors`:

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

By calling `EnableCors`, you just enable the framework, nothing more.